# Google App Script for assigning a certain score in for answers in Column D and display it in Column AE

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I hope someone can help me. I am trying to assign scores to the answers entered in Column D and display the scores in Column AE. I tried the code I write below but the results won't show up. Thanks.

```
    function Q1Scores() {
    var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
    var answers1 = sheet1.getRange('D:D').getValues();

    if(answers1 == "A Extremely low risk taker"){
      sheet1.getRange('AE:AE2').setvalue("1");
    }
      else if(answers1 == "B Very low risk taker"){
     sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setvalue("1.33");
    }
     else if(answers1 == "C Low risk taker"){
     sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setvalue("1.67");
    }
     else if(answers1 == "D Average risk taker"){
      sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setvalue("2");
    }
      else if(answers1 == "E High risk taker"){
      sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setvalue("2.33");
    }
      else if(answers1 == "F Very high risk taker"){
     sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setvalue("2.67");
    }
      else if(answers1 == "G Extremely high risk taker"){
      sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setvalue("3");
    }
    else{
      sheet1.getRange('AE2:AE').setValue("");
    } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `answers1` of `var answers1 = sheet1.getRange('D:D').getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. But, you are trying to compare this with a string like `answers1 == "A Extremely low risk taker"`. In this case, it is always false. I thought that this might be the reason for your current issue of `but the results won't show up`.
- And, about `sheet1.getRange('AE:AE2').setvalue("1");`, `v` is `setValue`. But, in this case, `1` is put into all rows. Please be careful about this.

When these points are reflected in your script, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function Q1Scores() {
  // This object is created from your showing script.
  var obj = {
    "A Extremely low risk taker": 1,
    "B Very low risk taker": 1.33,
    "C Low risk taker": 1.67,
    "D Average risk taker": 2,
    "E High risk taker": 2.33,
    "F Very high risk taker": 2.67,
    "G Extremely high risk taker": 3
  };
  var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet1 = ss1.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  var range = sheet1.getRange('D1:D' + sheet1.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues().map(([d]) => [obj[d.trim()] || ""]);
  range.offset(0, 27, values.length, 1).setValues(values);
}
```

- When this script is run, the number values like `1`, `1.33`,,, are put in to column "AE" depending on the cell value of column "D".
- In this modification, it supposes that the cell values of column "D" are "A Extremely low risk taker", "B Very low risk taker",,,. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)